# Microsoft Word without subscription

Tags: microsoft-word, office

I use word a lot, however I don't use onedrive at all.
I tried openoffice and Libreoffice, and didn't like it. The navigation panel, the chapters, the charts I put in my documents, all the formatting, it felt clunky.

I know that I can buy Office 2021 without a subscription. I am looking for options where I can buy paying it one time and keep the software, comparing the price. Anything I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance!